# PUT command for cartoDB API

Tags: carto

I am trying to update json file from local machine to cartodb.I used below command but it is not working.
curl -v  -F  file=@C:/Users/k/Desktop/In/da.json  --request "PUT" "https://account-name.cartodb.com/api/v1/synchronizations/Import-ID/sync_now?api_key={API-KEY}"

Is there any specific command for updating data from local machine?

Comment: PUT? should it be POST? http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/maps-api.html curl -X POST 'https://{account}.cartodb.com/api/v1/map/named/:template_id' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

Comment: Initially I used POST command for uploading data in to cartodb after that I am just trying to replace old data with new data.Every it is creating new file instead of replacing old file.

Answer (score 2):

Once you have created a Sync table you cannot update the field from which it's being updated.

Also, a Sync Table cannot be created from a local file. CartoDB needs the file to be publicly accessible in the Internet (or safe inside your Dropbox/GDrive account).

If you already have a Sync Table and you want to force a Sync, [just follow the API](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/import-api.html#force-a-synchronisation-action-on-a-sync-table):

```
curl -v --request "PUT" "https://{account}.cartodb.com/api/v1/synchronizations/<import_id>/sync_now?api_key={account API Key}" --header "Content-Length:0"
```

If you have a Sync Table but you want to Sync another file, you'll have to start from the beginning of the process, just creating a new table.

If you have a local file and you want it to be Synced, you can use Dropbox/Google Drive or use the [SQL API](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api.html) in order to add your data by pieces in CartoDB tables by using INSERT or UPDATE statements.

This question is very related to yours: [Can you force cartoDB to read a file as a synced table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/148911/can-you-force-cartodb-to-read-a-file-as-a-synced-table)