# Can you force cartoDB to read a file as a synced table

Tags: python, carto, curl

I'm writing a script that downloads from a data source every hour. I then do some processing on it and convert it to a kml saved in my google drive. As the data is updating every hour I want to be able to sync it with cartodb. However, the sync options are all greyed out. Do I need to upgrade to have access to synced table functions or is there a way to force cartoDB to recognise it as a synced table?

Answer (score 1):

Sync capabilities are only available for users with plans from John Snow up. If you have the feature, syncing a table can be done from the ui or from our [Import API](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/import-api.html).

If you don't have the feature, you can use the SQL API instead. This means that you will need to take care of the data and retrieve it from the KML file by yourself so that you can include it in INSERT or UPDATE statements.

The complete documentation of the SQL API is available [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/sql-api.html). If you're planning to create tables directly from this SQL API, please check [this guide](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/wiki/creating-tables-though-the-SQL-API) as it requires to do some magic (like CartoDBfying the tables).

Comment: Thanks I'll take a look at the sql api and accept the answer shortly